# Specrun Command Line Filters

Tags: specflow, specrun

Need some help here. I am trying to run specrun from a command line and it is ignoring everything but the first tag. Per some other posts, the help file is incorrect.

Help File

> [/filter:value]  Filter expression (overrides profile setting), e.g. '@mytag & !@othertag'

Gaspar has posted to use double quotes and that is identifying the first tag only. Tags are also case specfic so I have checked that.

How I am running:

> SpecRun.exe run Default.srprofile /baseFolder:D:\path /filter:"@Tag1 & !@Tag2" /log:specrun.log

Is anyone having luck with this? If so, how are you running?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is using a pipe.

> SpecRun.exe run Default.srprofile /baseFolder:D:\path /filter:"@Tag1 | @Tag2" /log:specrun.log